# PHP Notice: Undefined index: name in /path/to/file.php on line 2

Tags: php

I'm trying to send a form's data to someone's email via PHP.

However, I get a undefined index error on every variable, on every line.

`PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /path/to/file.php on line 2`

Form: https://jsfiddle.net/dg1ur9fc/

PHP:

```
<?php
/* Error Reporting */
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_POST)){
    $name   = $_POST['fullname'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $email  = $_POST['email'];
    $brand  = $_POST['brand'];
    $model  = $_POST['model'];
    $variant = $_POST['variant'];
    $screen = $_POST['screen'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $power = $_POST['power'];
    $battery = $_POST['battery'];
    $charge = $_POST['charge'];
    $calls = $_POST['calls'];
    $fcamera = $_POST['fcamera'];
    $rcamera = $_POST['rcamera'];
    $water = $_POST['water'];
    $wifi = $_POST['wifi'];
    $formcontent = "From: $name \n Contact: $number \n Device Brand: $brand \n Device Model: $model \n Device Variant: $variant \n Screen: $screen \n Housing: $body \n Is your device able to power on? $power \n Does your device have a fault battery? $battery \n Is your device able to charge? $charge \n Does your front camera work? $fcamera \n Does your rear camera work? $rcamera \n Is your device water damaged? $water \n Is your device able to connect using WiFi? $wifi";
    $recipient = "test@example.com";
    $subject = "Buyback Request";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
    /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: https://example.com");
    /* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
    exit;
}
?>
```

May I know what the issue is, and how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined). Try to Initializiate variables

Comment: share ur form too

Comment: @Rp9 Added the form.

Comment: there is no field having `name` _name_

Comment: @AhmedAli, I added a ```name = name``` parameter for the ``name`` input field of my form (see HTML form linked in OP; line 146 in the JSFiddle)

Comment: for double check replace `name` to `fullname`. I guess there is a conflict between them

Comment: Please use `isset()` for this

Comment: @AhmedAli not sure what you mean by use ```isset()```, could you show an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203874/discussion-between-ahmed-ali-and-narypigeon).

Comment: This question already has answers here: [PHP - Notice: Undefined index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707448/php-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Please add your form code too. from <form> to </form>. Now we don't know there is a problem when the form was submitted or the form data was incorrect.

Comment: @ThếAnhNguyễn look at the JSFiddle link for the form code.

Comment: @BloodyProgrammer I wrapped my PHP code in ```if(isset($_POST)){ ... }``` but to no avail. I've edited the code in the OP to reflect what I mean.

Comment: @emix No, it doesn't.

Comment: @narypigeon , i didn't understand what you actually doing and and your exact error, you also use smtp in this form, please provide complete code and error  for better solution !

Comment: @emix Okay, I have added ```isset()``` as linked, however, I am still unable to get an email.

Answer (score 0):

they are undefined on first load as there is no post yet. So you should always check for the existence of any post using

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['number']) && isset($_POST['email']) && pass all parameter here ){
```